# jqplot.replot does not work properly. legend is replaced by just 2 labels: "1" and "2"

Tags: javascript, jqplot

I'm able to plot a chart successfully, but calling replot corrupts the chart and data.

```
var jqChart;

chartConfig.data([
            ['material', 20],
            ['transportS2M', 10],
            ['processing', 14],
            ['packaging', 12],
            ['transportM2D', 30],
            ['use', 14]
    ]);


jqChart = $.jqplot("chart", [chartConfig.data()], 
    {
        seriesDefaults: {
            // Make this a pie chart.
            renderer: jQuery.jqplot.PieRenderer,
            rendererOptions: {
                // Put data labels on the pie slices.
                // By default, labels show the percentage of the slice.
                showDataLabels: true
            }
        },
        legend: {
            show: true,
            placement: 'outside',
            rendererOptions: {
                numberRows: 1
            },
            location: 's',
            marginTop: '15px'
        }
    });

// example to change the data
setTimeout(function () {
chartConfig.data([
        ['material', 10],
        ['transportS2M', 20],
        ['processing', 14],
        ['packaging', 22],
        ['transportM2D', 20],
        ['use', 14]
]);

}, 4000);


chartConfig.data.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    var opts = {
        data: newValue
    };
    if (jqChart) {
        jqChart.replot(opts);
        console.log("chart replotted", opts);
    }
});
```

After the initial call to create jqChart, the "_plotdata" property shows this in chrome variable inspector:

```
_plotData: Array[2]
0: Array[6]
    0: Array[2]
        0: "material"
        1: 20
        length: 2
        __proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
2: Array[2]
3: Array[2]
4: Array[2]
5: Array[2]
length: 6
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[6]
length: 2
```

(each of the arrays is the same as the expanded one except for actual values).

I have no idea why plotdata seems to have a duplicate array, but it displays perfectly.

As soon as the "replot" call is done, the "_plotdata" property goes a bit berserk:

```
_plotData: Array[12]
0: Array[2]
   0: Array[2]
      0: 1
      1: "material"
      length: 2
      __proto__: Array[0]
   1: Array[2]
   length: 2
   __proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
0: Array[2]
0: 1
1: "transportS2M"
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
1: Array[2]
length: 2
__proto__: Array[0]
2: Array[2]
3: Array[2]
4: Array[2]
5: Array[2]
6: Array[0]
7: Array[2]
8: Array[0]
9: Array[2]
10: Array[0]
11: Array[2]
length: 12
```

...and the pie chart disappears. The legend is replaced by just 2 labels: "1" and "2".

I'm pretty sure I'm calling this correctly, so I'm confused about why the _plotdata property is going so berserk when updated!

Answer (score 0):

Well I fiddled around and managed to cure it by changing my data subscription method to:

```
chartConfig.data.subscribe(function (newValue) {
    if (jqChart) {
        jqChart.series[0].data = newValue;
        jqChart.replot();
        console.log("chart replotted", newValue);
    }
});
```

All I'm doing is manually targetting the specific series and calling replot without the options.  No idea why it works, but it does.